# Creating a reusable method timeout class in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to create a class that lets me call methods with a specified timout. I have the actual timeout implementation working, but am having trouble encapsulating this into a class successfully.

I have decided at this time to limit myself to working with just the 5 Action delegates to put a timeout on methods that take 0 - 4 arguments. For the purposes of this question i will use the one argument variant of Action.

My Ideal calling syntax would be something like this:

```
Action<int> a = new TimeoutAction(i => i + 1)
{
    Timeout = Timespan.FromSeconds(10)
}
```

or this:

```
Action<int> a = (x => x + 1).Timeout(Timespan.FromSeconds(10))
```

I am almost sure that the first version isnt possible as there is no way to inherit from a delegate. The second may be possible by using an extension method on the `Delegate` type.

A final fallback would be to create static methods that take in the appropriate delegate type and return a Delegate with the same signature but with the timeouts included.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last suggestion would be the right way:

> A final fallback would be to create
>   static methods that take in the
>   appropriate delegate type and return a
>   Delegate with the same signature but
>   with the timeouts included.

In other words:

```
public static Action<T> Timeout<T>(this Action<T> action, TimeSpan timeSpan);
public static Action<T1, T2> Timeout<T1, T2>(this Action<T1, T2> action, TimeSpan timeSpan);
public static Func<T, TResult> Timeout<T, TResult>(this Func<T, TResult> action, TimeSpan timeSpan);
public static Func<T1, T2, TResult> Timeout<T1, T2, TResult>(this Func<T1, T2, TResult> action, TimeSpan timeSpan);
/* snip the rest of the Action<...> and Func<...> overloads */
```

*"Why can't I just declare one method?"*

You could declare one method that accepts a `Delegate` and returns a `Delegate`, but then you'd lose the delegate type information (your second example wouldn't compile).

Unfortunately, the following example isn't valid C# -- you can't use `Delegate` as a type parameter constraint:

```
public static TDelegate Timeout<TDelegate>(this TDelegate d, Timespan timespan) where TDelegate : Delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for that. Either [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) or [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the approach to a Timed Lock as described [here](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/03/23/locking)?

Answer (score -1):

Well, a lambda expression won't "have a type" (anything you can 'dot' or extension method) until you wrap it in e.g.

```
new DelType(lambda)
```

or

```
Stat.Method(lambda)
```

or otherwise provide context, so I suggest the final option (static method):

```
Timeout.Action(lambda, timeoutVal)
```